# Specific custom Repository not found with getRepository but others work OK

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my app I have several custom repositories which are  mapped with respective Entity classes and orm.yml files.

They are all defined in the same manner and structure apart of course their names and members.

Yet when I try to get the custom repositories, just for a specific one I get the super class of the repository instead of the correct repository.

```
$a = $this->em->getRepository('MyAppCommonBundle:Activity'); //doesn't work

$b = $this->em->getRepository('MyAppCommonBundle:Activity:User'); //works

$c= $this->em->getRepository('MyAppCommonBundle:ActivityStatus'); //works
```

MyAppCommonBundle is defined:
MyAppCommonBundle' => 'MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity

$a returns the wrong  super class Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository while $b returns the correct MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository\UserRepository
and $c is MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository\ActivityStatus

All Entities are in the same folder   MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity.
All repositories are in the same place too  MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository.

Activity.orm.yml:

```
MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity\Activity:
    type: entity
    table: activity
    repositoryClass: MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository\ActivityRepository
    indexes:
```

and for example User.orm.yml:

```
MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository\UserRepository
```

Activity Repository:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; 


class ActivityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
```

User Repository:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\CommonBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository; 
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
...
```

As stated above, User and other repositories are found, Activity is not...

I tried clearing cache, rebuilding entities with no effect.
Obviously tried to look for typos etc. but looks good.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: No ORM annotations in your Activity entity?  No orm.XML files floating around?

Comment: And check if your repo has the right namespace and the same class name as the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Cerad, there are no ORM annotations that are relevant.
Activity entity:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Activity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="activity"...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Activity
{...
```

User entity:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\CommonBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user"...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
....
```

There are no orm.xml files at all.
And Frank, yes, the repository class names are the same as their file names.

Comment: You have a somewhat unusual definition of relevant.  Doctrine does not allow you to use different types of mapping (ie yaml and annotations) within the same entity manager.  Use one of the other but not both.  And for info, use the Edit link in the lower left corner of your question to update it.  What you posted here is obviously not an answer.